# GC as a thread synchronization mechanism

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, synchronization, clr

Reading [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) (excellent book by the way) I stumbled across the following note:

> There are many nice features about a garbage collected system: no memory leaks, no
>   memory corruption, no address space fragmentation, and a reduced working set. And now, a
>   new one: synchronization. **That’s right, you can use the GC as a thread synchronization
>   mechanism.** Question: How can you know when all threads are done using an object?
>   Answer: the GC finalizes the object. There is nothing wrong with taking advantage of all the
>   GC features as you architect your software.

How's that?

---

Does he meant that I can use Finalize to notify some other "live" object that this object in question is not accessed by any thread anymore?

If so, isn't that a pretty bad idea due to the fact that:

- The Finalize call is non-deterministic (it's called whenever the GC feels like it).
- If Finalize raises an exception (it's calling some other object, not that impossible to happen) it terminates the process since there's no way to catch such exception.

Comment: The comment also seems false. Anyone that has done some larger .NET projects knows that memory fragmentation and memory leaks are still very much possible. Additionally, a lot of programmers will probably be able to tell you how many times they've been asked why their .NET application "is using so much memory".

Comment: Richter's statement is not untrue.  That there's baggage attached is already clear to you, of course you can't depend on getting the finalizer to run at the very instant the threads stop using the object.  Just something to stick in your back-pocket, doing it explicitly with, say,  CountDownEvent isn't that pretty either.

Comment: I'm asking for help to grasp what the author stated and there's people voting for closing as "opinion based"?? I can't even...